# Internal mass distribution in a sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

Suppose I have a sphere. What I want to know is: *how does the mass distribution inside this sphere affect its motion?.*

For example, if I have that the top half of the sphere is heavier than the lower half: *how would this change its behavior when moving, and how would it affect its velocity and acceleration if I am exerting the same force on it, or on a sphere with equal mass distribution?*

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Well, translatory would be unaffected. Rotation would be highly affected due to shift in center of mass and moment of inertia.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rigid body equations.

For translation:
$$\bf{F}=M\bf{a_{CM}}$$

where $\bf{F}$ is the total force acting on it, $M$ the total mass of the body and $\bf{a_{CM}}$ the acceleration of the center of mass.

For rotation:
$$\bf{T}=I\bf{\alpha}$$
where $\bf{T}$ is the total torque, $I$ the mass moment of inertia and $\bf{\alpha}$ the angular velocity.

Basically, the center of mass translates as if it were a point-particle of mass $M$ under the influence on the acting forces. In addition, the body rotates according to the second equation.

What then changes if you have a mass distribution $\rho(\bf{r})$ is the position of the center of mass $$\bf{r}_{CM}={1\over M}\int \bf{r} \rho(\bf{r})dV$$ and the moment of inertia of the body $$I=\int h^2 \rho(\bf{r})dV$$ $h$ being the distance from the chosen axis of rotation.

In the case of the sphere you mentioned, it would have the center of mass shifted towards the heavier side.

Comment: Ahem, the equation for rotation is $$ \bf{T}=I\bf{\alpha} + \bf{\omega} \times I \bf{\omega} $$

Answer (score 0):

A non-uniform mass distribution would affect the center of mass of the sphere as well as its moment of inertia.  An object resting on a flat surface will in general have its minimum potential energy when its center of mass is closest to the surface.  For a sphere with uniform density, this doesn't make a difference;  the center of mass is at the center of the sphere, and so the actual orientation of the sphere doesn't make a difference.  But for a sphere composed of two hemispheres of different density, the center of mass would be shifted towards the more massive hemisphere, along the line orthogonal to the "glued" faces of the hemispheres.  This would mean that a sphere composed this way, if rolled gently along a flat and level surface, would tend to come to rest with its heavier half touching the surface.

A sphere with an uneven mass distribution will also in general have a different moment of inertia from a sphere of uniform density.  This affects the motion of rolling objects because of the differing ratios between translational and rotational kinetic energy.  The classic example here is the [disk vs. ring race](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHQOctEvtTY).  A sphere with an off-center center of mass would show other weird effects as it descended the ramp (i.e., it would speed up & slow down as the center of mass rose and fell relative to the ramp), but these effects might be present as well.  Even if you had a sphere with a mass distribution that was spherically symmetric but non-uniform, this test could let you distinguish between such a sphere and a uniform sphere.

(I have been known to ask the following question on my final exams:  an eccentric billionaire offers you two spheres of the same size, one made of solid aluminum and one made of gold with a hollow core.  You may pick one and keep it;  obviously you want to pick the gold one.  The spheres are painted so you cannot tell which one is which by visual examination alone.  Without damaging the spheres, how do you figure out which one to choose?  There are several possible answers, and one of them is "roll them down a hill and keep the one that rolls slower.")

Answer (score 0):

If you consider friction-free motion, then there is no difference. All the energy used by the sphere is converted to kinetic energy.

If however the sphere is rolling, then there is an observable change. Not all the energy becomes kinetic energy, part of it goes now to rotational energy and as a result the sphere goes slower. How slower depends exactly on the mass distribution.

First of all, we need to introduce the moment of inertia:
$I = \int \limits_V \vec{r}_{\perp}^{2}\rho(\vec r)\,\mathrm{d}V$,
where $\vec{r}_{\perp}$ is the perpendicular position from the rotational axis and $\rho$ is the density of the object.

Rotational energy is: $E_{rot} = \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity. The higher the moment of inertia, the higher the energy needed to rotate the object.

Now let's consider a sphere of radius $R$ and mass $m$. As a few examples we consider a sphere of uniform density, one with a left and a right uniform densities, another one with top and bottom uniform densities (same as before, but rolled on a different axis), a hollow sphere and a sphere with a density gradient.

In all the examples the sphere rolls in the $x$ direction and the rotational axis is parallel to the $y$ axis, so $\vec{r}_{\perp}^2 = x^2+z^2$.

To simplify calculations, we will use cylindrical coordinates: $x = r \cos(\varphi), y = y, z = r \sin(\varphi)$, so $\vec{r}_{\perp}^2 = r^2$ and $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z = r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\mathrm{d}y$.

$\rho_a (\vec{r}) = \rho_0$
$I_a = \int \limits_{-R}^{R} \mathrm{d}y \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\varphi \int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}} \mathrm{d} r\, r^3 \rho_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}\rho_0 \int \limits_{-R}^{R} (R^2-y^2)^2 \mathrm{d}y = \frac{8}{15} \pi\rho_0\,R^5$
Since $m = \frac{4}{3}\pi \rho_0 R^3$, then $I_a = \frac{2}{5} m R^2$.

$\rho_b(\vec{r}) = \begin{cases} \rho_1, & y < 0 \\ \rho_2, & y > 0 \end{cases}$
In this case the $y$ integral splits in two: $I_b = \frac{\pi}{2}\left( \rho_1 \int \limits_{-R}^{0} (R^2-y^2)^2 \mathrm{d}y + \rho_2 \int \limits_{0}^{R} (R^2-y^2)^2 \mathrm{d}y \right) = \frac{4}{15} \pi (\rho_1+\rho_2) R^5$ and since $m = \frac{2}{3} \pi (\rho_1+\rho_2) R^3$, then again is $I_b = \frac{2}{5} m R^2$.

$\rho_c(\vec{r}) = \begin{cases} \rho_1, & \varphi < \pi \\ \rho_2, & \varphi > \pi \end{cases}$
In this case the $\varphi$ integral splits in two: $I_c = \frac{\pi}{4}\left( \rho_1 \int \limits_{-R}^{R} (R^2-y^2)^2 \mathrm{d}y + \rho_2 \int \limits_{-R}^{R} (R^2-y^2)^2 \mathrm{d}y \right) = \frac{4}{15} \pi (\rho_1+\rho_2) R^5 = \frac{2}{5} m R^2$.

$\rho_d(\vec{r}) = \rho_0$ between $R'$ and $R$
$I_d = 2\pi\rho_0 \left(\int \limits_{-R}^{-R'} \mathrm{d}y \int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}} \mathrm{d} r\, r^3 + \int \limits_{-R'}^{R'} \mathrm{d}y \int \limits_{\sqrt{R'^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}} \mathrm{d} r\, r^3 + \int \limits_{R'}^{R} \mathrm{d}y \int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}} \mathrm{d} r\, r^3 \right)$
The expression is a little bit more complicated, to avoid negative values when $y > R'$ and $y < -R'$. Then, after all the calculations is $I_d = \frac{8}{15} \pi\rho_0 (R^5 - R'^5)$ and since $m = \frac{4}{3}\pi \rho_0 (R^3-R'^3)$, then is $I_d = \frac{2}{5} m \frac{R^5-R'^5}{R^3-R'^3}$.

$\rho_e(\vec{r}) = \rho_1 + \frac{|\vec{r}|}{R}(\rho_2 - \rho_1)$, so that the density is $\rho_1$ at the center and grows/decreases linearly towards $\rho_2$ at the borders.
$I_e = \int \limits_{-R}^{R} \mathrm{d}y \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\varphi \int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}} \mathrm{d} r\, r^3 (\rho_1 + \frac{\sqrt{r^2+y^2}}{R} (\rho_2-\rho_1)) =\\ \frac{8}{15} \pi\rho_1 R^5 + \frac{2}{15} \pi(\rho_2-\rho_1) R^2 \int \limits_{-R}^{R} (3R^2-5y^2) \mathrm{d}y =\\ \frac{8}{15} \pi\rho_1 R^5 + \frac{16}{45} \pi(\rho_2-\rho_1) R^5 = \frac{8}{45} \pi (\rho_1+2\rho_2) R^5$
Since $m = \frac{\pi}{3} R^3 (\rho_1 + 3\rho_2)$, then is $I_e = \frac{8}{15} m \frac{\rho_1 + 2\rho_2}{\rho_1 + 3\rho_2} R^2$.

Sorry I left out all the calculations, but they were really too much. As you can see the first three cases all have the same moment of inertia, so there is no difference in the way they spin. The last two however are different:

- $I_d$ is greater than $I_a$, so the hollow sphere will require more energy to be spun, since all the mass is concentrated away from the rotation axis. In the limit $R' \to R$, $I_d \to \frac{2}{3} m R^2$.
- $I_e$ depends on which density is greatest. In the limit $\rho_1 \to 0$, $I_e \to \frac{16}{45} m R^2 < I_a$, while in the limit $\rho_2 \to 0$, $I_e \to \frac{8}{15} m R^2 > I_a$. Curiously, this situation seems to say the opposite of the one before: when the matter is concentrated around the axis, it is harder to spin the sphere.

It is possible that the last result depends on the different matter distribution. I really hope that all my calculations are correct. As a first check, putting $\rho_1 = \rho_2 = \rho_0$ and $R' = 0$ in the formulas always result in $I_a$, so it is probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for any shape is that there are three quantities that define the rigid body motion. Regardless of the shape, two bodies with identical quantities will behave the same.

1. Total Mass

   $$m = \iiint \rho\, {\rm d}V$$
2. Center of Mass

   $$ \boldsymbol{c} = \pmatrix{x_C \\ y_C \\ z_C} = \frac{1}{m} \iiint \rho\, \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z}\, {\rm d}V  $$
3. Mass Moment of Inertia Tensor (at origin)

   $$ \mathbf{I} = \left[ \matrix{I_{xx} & I_{xy} & I_{xz} \\ I_{x y} & I_{yy} & I_{yz} \\ I_{xz} & I_{yz} & I_{zz}} \right] = \iiint \rho \, \left[ \matrix{y^2+z^2 & -x y & - x z \\ -x y & x^2+z^2 & -y z \\ -x z & -y z & x^2+y^2} \right]  \,{\rm d}V $$

   and at the center of mass

   $$ \mathbf{I}_C = \mathbf{I} - m \left[ \matrix{y_C^2+z_C^2 & -x_C y_C & - x_C z_C \\ -x_C y_C & x_C^2+z_C^2 & -y_C z_C \\ -x_C z_C & -y_C z_C & x_C^2+y_C^2} \right] $$

Any two shapes with the same $m$, $\boldsymbol{c}$ and $\mathrm{I}_C$ have the *exact* same dynamic behavior.